# If I delete a photo on ICloud from both my photos and the 'recently deleted' folder, can it still be recovered?

Tags: icloud, data-recovery

Does Apple still save the image(s) somewhere for an undisclosed period of time, or once it's deleted, it's gone everywhere for good? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple only holds photos for [limited time in deleted items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246016/can-you-recover-deleted-photos-from-the-recently-deleted-section-in-your-album). That is your chance to reconsider. You could open a case with support to confirm, but the place to get these is from local backups. iCloud isn’t a backup just like files on your devices aren’t a backup.

So sorry if this wasn’t your expected answer. It’s never good to lose data or learn you didn’t have backups.